# Error grouping by the sum of one column to the general value of the other

Tags: mysql, sql, join, having

I have a list of parameters the first are a date range @start_dt and @end_dt one of my fields is mode. if mode = 1, the query is run one way if mode - 2, another, etc. I've got 7 possible versions.

when mode = 6, what I want to say is 
pull all the columns between the date range list below and where one column pmt_rcvd_amt doesn't equal to the sum of sli_paid_amt. Now I want the sli_paid_amt grouped by customer_no 
    `Where a.create_dt between @start_dt and @end_dt` 
    `and a.pmt_rcvd_amt <> sum(a.sli_paid_amt)`

For example:

```
customer_no sli_due_amt pmt_rcvd_amt`
85244305    200.00  200.00
74500386    50.00   219.00
74500386    219.00  219.00
74500386    10.00   219.00
86119821    NULL    NULL
```

I want it to take for customer_no 74500386 
 it to group them (sum all the sli_due_amt) so 219 + 50. + 10 thus 279 and then compare it to the 219 in pmt_rcvd_amt column. (those values are going to be the same)

my code looks like this ...

```
select distinct 
        a.id_key ,
        a.customer_no ,
        a.customer_prefix ,
        a.customer_lname 
        ... 
        a.current_child_price ,
        a.current_other_price 
        from LV_CHC_TOURS_RSV_DATA a
        left outer join LT_CHC_TOURS_RSV_LANG b on a.language = b.id 
        left outer join LV_CHC_TOURS_RSV_CS c on a.add_text = c.source_no 
        Where a.create_dt between @start_dt and @end_dt 
        and a.pmt_rcvd_amt <> sum(a.sli_paid_amt)

Error Message: An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.
```

I then changed it to try and use having in my code:

```
from LV_CHC_TOURS_RSV_DATA a
        left outer join LT_CHC_TOURS_RSV_LANG b on a.language = b.id 
        left outer join LV_CHC_TOURS_RSV_CS c on a.add_text = c.source_no 
        Where a.create_dt between @start_dt and @end_dt 
        group by a.customer_no
        having sum(a.sli_paid_amt) <> a.pmt_rcvd_amt
```

and now I get the following error message:

```
Column 'LV_CHC_TOURS_RSV_DATA.pmt_rcvd_amt' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

I know its a bit odd - but I want for a given customer_no to sum all the sli_due_amts and then see if they equal the distinct value of pmt_rcvd_amt. because those distinct values will be the same in each line.

what my desired output is:

```
customer_no sli_due_amt pmt_rcvd_amt`
74500386    50.00   219.00
74500386    219.00  219.00
74500386    10.00   219.00
```

because: 50 + 219 + 10 doesn't equal to 219 (grouped by customer 74500386)

Comment: Can you give us the expected output using the sample you gave us pls? Also, note that  "those distinct values will be the same in each line" it's not a good thing to have in a database. Imagine you want to change the pmt_rcvd_amt in one record, you'll need to change it in all the others.

Comment: If you know for a fact the value of a.pmt_rcvd_amt will always be the same for every row, you can use an arbitrary aggregate function like min or max just to get back "some" value. The "correct" way to do this is to create a derive table containing the aggregate data, and another derive table containing the singleton value to which you're comparing it. While there are plenty of times it's simply out of your control, I agree with @LuisAlves that this sounds like poor database design.

Comment: Use a subquery in your WHERE clause. So that a.pmt_rcvd_amt <> (some query that retrieves the SUM for the customer)

Comment: @LuisAlves I know that its not good to have the same data -- but sadly for this particular example its unavoidable.  I can't create a table to derive the aggregate data - the system we use requires one table to store data for certain set up - both those fields are necessary there is no way around it. That is why I'm stuck trying to pull the correct data with this setup.

Comment: The error in the query is what the error message says, you need to select the field a.pmt_rcvd_amt

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT a.customer_no, SUM(a.sli_paid_amt), MAX(a.pmt_rcvd_amt) AS [Payment Amount], MAX(some_other_field), ...
 from LV_CHC_TOURS_RSV_DATA a
        left outer join LT_CHC_TOURS_RSV_LANG b on a.language = b.id 
        left outer join LV_CHC_TOURS_RSV_CS c on a.add_text = c.source_no 
        Where a.create_dt between @start_dt and @end_dt 
        group by a.customer_no
        having sum(a.sli_paid_amt) <> [Payment Amount]
```

If the field is not in the group by, it must be an aggregate function such as SUM/MAX etc... If you group by customer id the above query should work. Then just wrap the fields in your select statement with MAX(-), because MAX can be used with char fields also.

Comment: The problem is that I want the query to return the fields individually in other words i need three lines returned for customer_no  74500386  and i need the unique elements - the 10, 219 and 50 separate so i can't max them in the select statement. in other words i need the query to return all the unique lines where the sum of the one field doesn't math the value in the other but i still need to see all the parts of the fields.

Comment: Can you group by the fields also?

Comment: No, sadly I simply want to test to see if their sum (grouped by customer_no) is equivalent and return those distinct rows if its not.

Answer (score 0):

In `HAVING` clause you can have only aggregate functions. `a.pmt_rcvd_amt` is the same for each row so you can use `min(a.pmt_rcvd_amt)` or `max(a.pmt_rcvd_amt)`
In below code subquery returns numbers of all customers which satisfy your requirement. Then they are used by main query to select all needed rows.

so try this:

```
select 
    a.id_key ,
    a.customer_no ,
    a.customer_prefix ,
    a.customer_lname 
    ... 
    a.current_child_price ,
    a.current_other_price 
from LV_CHC_TOURS_RSV_DATA a 
    left outer join LT_CHC_TOURS_RSV_LANG b on a.language = b.id 
    left outer join LV_CHC_TOURS_RSV_CS c on a.add_text = c.source_no 
where a.customer_no in 
( select a1.customer_no from LV_CHC_TOURS_RSV_DATA a1       
    Where a1.create_dt between @start_dt and @end_dt 
    group by a1.customer_no
    having sum(a1.sli_paid_amt) <> min(a1.pmt_rcvd_amt))
```

Comment: When i try this option I get the following error: Column 'LV_CHC_TOURS_RSV_DATA.id_key' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. The id_key is another column in my query.

Comment: so your saying i'm pulling the query as is - where the customer_no and filter the date range/ and aggregates in the internal select?

Comment: Inner query returns only different `customer_no` which satisfy requirement. They are used by main query

Comment: This doesn't work because there are a bunch of fields in the linked tables that are also pulled in the main query - if we nest them then we get a bunch of errors like: The multi-part identifier "b.description" could not be bound.

Comment: I understand the logic, but it seems to be coming back blank - no data is being returned.

Comment: @YelizavetaYR In your question you sometimes refer to sli_paid_amt column and sometimes to sli_due_amt'. So I don't know what you realy want. Try to hange in my query sli_paid_amt` to sli_due_amt' and check. Try also removing condition checking a1.create_dt`. If query still will not return any row then you will have to provide more details to give me a chance to find error

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, first you need to sum up sli_due_amt for each customer, and then you want to return the individual rows, excluding customers who have a pmt_rcvd_amt = the summed sli_due_amt.

So:

```
WITH Summed as
(select
customer_no,
sum(sli_due_amt) as sli_sum
from LV_CHC_TOURS_RSV_DATA...
GROUP BY cust_no
)

    select *
    from
    LV_CHC_TOURS_RSV_DATA t1
    inner join summed
      on t1.customer_no = summed.customer_no
      and t1.pmt_rcvd_amt <> sli_sum
```

I grossly over-simplified your query, of course.

Comment: I don't need to sum them for the output -- i need to sum them to do a comparison - where the sum of sli_due_amt doesn't equals the pmt_rcvd_amt - but i want the output set to be unique individual columns.